# exponentialRampToValueAtTime not fading out with Safari

Tags: javascript, audio

I am just learning about audio in JavaScript and I am having trouble with the audio not cracking.

I am trying to use exponentialRampToValueAtTime, but it seems to only be adjusting the time, with no fade out, and thus there is still a cracking noise.

This is my code:

```
        const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        let context = new AudioContext()
        let o = context.createOscillator()
        let g = context.createGain()
        
        o.connect(g)
        g.connect(context.destination)
         
      g.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.00001, 0.04);
        o.start(0)
```

Comment: is this problem only with safari?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be.  I just tested it out on Firefox and I'm having the same issue as well.

Comment: as far as I've read, firefox "partially supports" that method, so perhaps not the best other browser to check - have you tried running `g.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.00001, 0.04);` after `o.start(0)`? - though, in either case you'll get `0.04` seconds of rapidly faading sound (assuming gain is at `1` by default of course)

Comment: By the way, thanks so much for the help!  I tried placing it afterwards, and still same issue.  I've tried it on both opera and chrome, and I am having a different issue in that they will only make the sound in response to a user action.  For reference, I am using the code from this site to try and implement sound into my game: https://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/

Comment: Okay, so I solved the problem, it seems to be an issue with bot Firefox and Safari.    

I needed to add: 
 `` g.gain.setValueAtTime(1, context.currentTime); ``

Comment: would it be `context.currentTime + 0.04` ? but that does make sense compared with the example given in the `exponentialRampToValueAtTime` documentation

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  After looking at the documentation on Mozilla and thinking about it, that makes more sense!  Thanks so much!!!